# Search multiple patterns in each lines and output it on a new file

Tags: text-processing, logs

Here is the sample file. The actual log is way bigger than this.

```
user@linux:~$ cat log.txt 
[24/09/2018:22:41:49 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_BA2" c-ip=x.x.x.x cs-bytes=1198 cs-categories="Technology/Internet" cs-host=shavar.services.mozilla.com cs-ip=y.y.y.y cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=60 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[24/09/2018:17:45:44 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=x.x.x.x cs-bytes=152450 cs-categories="Business/Economy" cs-host=cvshipping.ups.com cs-ip=z.z.z.z cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=268 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[24/09/2018:17:44:03 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=x.x.x.x cs-bytes=1795 cs-categories="Software Downloads" cs-host=blocklist.addons.mozilla.org cs-ip=z.z.z.z cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=61 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[24/09/2018:17:41:44 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=x.x.x.x cs-bytes=3882 cs-categories="Web Ads/Analytics" cs-host=cebwa.d2.sc.omtrdc.net cs-ip=z.z.z.z cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=35 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[20/09/2018:15:48:50 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=a.a.a.a cs-auth-group=Domain%20Users cs-bytes=227 cs-categories="Web Ads/Analytics;Suspicious" cs-host=data35.adlooxtracking.com cs-ip=b.b.b.b cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" cs-username=johndoe duration=0 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED

[20/09/2018:15:48:35 GMT] "PROXY_SERVER_AA2" c-ip=a.a.a.a cs-auth-group=Domain%20Users cs-bytes=3201 cs-categories="Search Engines/Portals" cs-host=www.google.com cs-ip=b.b.b.b cs-method=CONNECT cs-uri-path=/ cs-uri-port=443 cs-uri-scheme=tcp cs-User-Agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0" cs-username=johndoe dnslookup-time=0 duration=117 rs-status=0 s-action=TCP_TUNNELED
user@linux:~$
```

My goal is to get timestamp, category, and the hostname for each line and redirect it to a new file.

**timestamp** (inside `[ ]`)

```
user@linux:~$ sed -n 's/^.*\[//p' log.txt | cut -d ']' -f1
24/09/2018:22:41:49 GMT
24/09/2018:17:45:44 GMT
24/09/2018:17:44:03 GMT
24/09/2018:17:41:44 GMT
20/09/2018:15:48:50 GMT
20/09/2018:15:48:35 GMT
user@linux:~$
```

**hostname** (after `cs-host=`)

```
user@linux:~$ sed -n 's/^.*cs-host=//p' log.txt | cut -d\  -f1
shavar.services.mozilla.com
cvshipping.ups.com
blocklist.addons.mozilla.org
cebwa.d2.sc.omtrdc.net
data35.adlooxtracking.com
www.google.com
user@linux:~$
```

**category** (between`cs-categories="` and `"`)

```
user@linux:~$ sed -n 's/^.*cs-categories="//p' log.txt | cut -d '"' -f1
Technology/Internet
Business/Economy
Software Downloads
Web Ads/Analytics
Web Ads/Analytics;Suspicious
Search Engines/Portals
user@linux:~$
```

Instead of executing `sed` command one by one, is it possible to run a single command to produce an output like this?

**Expected Output**

```
24/09/2018:22:41:49 GMT    shavar.services.mozilla.com      Technology/Internet
24/09/2018:17:45:44 GMT    cvshipping.ups.com               Business/Economy
24/09/2018:17:44:03 GMT    blocklist.addons.mozilla.org     Software Downloads
24/09/2018:17:41:44 GMT    cebwa.d2.sc.omtrdc.net           Web Ads/Analytics
20/09/2018:15:48:50 GMT    data35.adlooxtracking.com        Web Ads/Analytics;Suspicious
20/09/2018:15:48:35 GMT    www.google.com                   Search Engines/Portals
```

Also, if you have better solution for this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How far would

```
sed -r '/^$/d; s/^[^[]*[[]([^]]*)[]].*cs-categories="([^"]*)".*cs-host=([^ ]*) .*/\1\t\3\t\2/' file
24/09/2018:22:41:49 GMT shavar.services.mozilla.com Technology/Internet
24/09/2018:17:45:44 GMT cvshipping.ups.com  Business/Economy
24/09/2018:17:44:03 GMT blocklist.addons.mozilla.org    Software Downloads
24/09/2018:17:41:44 GMT cebwa.d2.sc.omtrdc.net  Web Ads/Analytics
20/09/2018:15:48:50 GMT data35.adlooxtracking.com   Web Ads/Analytics;Suspicious
20/09/2018:15:48:35 GMT www.google.com  Search Engines/Portals
```

get you?

```
sed -r '                        use extended regular expressions in the script
/^$/d                           delete empty lines

s/^[^[]*[[]([^]]*)[]].*         look for date time string between square brackets and prepare for 
                                the first "back reference"
cs-categories="([^"]*)".*       look for the string after cs-categories and prepare for second "b r"
cs-host=([^ ]*)                 look for the string after cs-host and prepare for third "b r"
.*/\1\t\3\t\2/                  create output line from back references separated by <TAB> chars.
'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using perl with look-aheads: this way it doesn't matter if the host comes before or after the categories

```
perl -lne '
    m(
        ^\[ (.*?) \]                   # match the timestamp
        (?=.* cs-categories= "(.+?)")  # look ahead for the category
        (?=.* cs-host= (\S+) )         # look ahead for the host
    )x
    and print join ",", $1,$2,$3
' log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @glenn. The perl code looks better and easier to read but it doesn't really work with sample data above.

Comment: It doesn't provide *exactly* the output you were looking for, but yes it does work with that data. What do you think I tested with?

Answer (score 0):

How about using awk:

```
awk '{t=""; h=""; c=""; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /^\[/) {t=$i} if ($i ~/^cs-host=/) {h=$i} if ($i ~ /^cs-categories=/) {c=$i}} if ((t != "") && (h != "") && (c != "")) printf("%s %s %s\n", t, h, c)}' _inputfile_
```

This is a rough estimate of what you could do.  Basically it just loops through each whitespace field in a given line and checks if the line starts with a certain string.  If then puts the value of that field into a certain variable.  After all of the fields have been processed, if all 3 fields are not blank, it prints out the fields.  It then moves onto the next line in the input file.

I did not do anything to deal with white space in the string.  You could do further checks within one of the existing checks to see if the string ends with a double-quote.  If not, append the next field to the variable.

I also did not do anything with substrings to get rid of things like [, ] and ".  I leave that as an exercise for you.  :)

Comment: 1) unreadable, add some newlines to your code. 2) wrong results (category values can contain spaces)